# Is there a converter for String?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, bean-validation

For converting String values in JSF bean validation, which converter will be used?
Like for numeric values we use `<f:convertNumber>` and for date we use `<f:convertDataTime>`.
My code snipest are as follows:
JSF page:

```
<h:inputText id="Name" label="Name" value="#{employee.eName}"/>
<h:message for="Name" styleClass="errorMessages"/>
```

Bean class:

```
public class Employee implements Serializable{
    @NotNull @Size(min = 3, max = 30)
    String eName;
}
```

Comment: Can you post an example of what you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`String` doesn't have a default converter. Request parameters are `String` already.

If you intend to hook a custom converter on `String`, use

```
@FacesConverter(forClass=String.class)
public class StringConverter implements Converter {

    // ...

}
```

The only use case I've seen for this is to set them to `null` instead of empty string, but that can also be achieved by setting the following context param in `web.xml`.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

This way the `@NotNull` annotation will be triggered when you submit an empty string. Otherwise you have to use Hibernate-specific `@NotBlank` instead.

#### See also

- [JSF 2.0 tutorial with Eclipse and Glassfish - chapter "Prepare JSF project" point 6](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/01/jsf-20-tutorial-with-eclipse-and.html#PrepareJSFWebProjectInEclipse)

Comment: One more use case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8327848/802058.